# Navigation Bar title image distortion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add this image to my navigation bar with the following code:

[image]

Please note the original image has no BG color and is cropped down.

Original:

[image]

Using this code:

```
 self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarLogo"]];
```

When I run the application on a 5S I get a distorted image:

[image]

As you can see the image is slightly distorted, can anyone explain the reason for the distortion and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because the image is not correctly sized. You have to look at the dimensions of the Navigation bar and assign it an image of equal proportion, otherwise, your image will be distorted to fit the space! Hope this helps.

the navigation bar is 64x320, hence your image have to be 128px*640px to fit appropriately.

Check this out for a walkthrough: 
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: what do you mean Nick? When you deal with retina pixels you usually refer to them divided by 2.

Comment: I created a new image 88x640 and put it on and still get distortion. It seems to want to upsize the image.

Comment: hmmm, create one with bigger height and tell me what happens, I will see if thats the correct size for the nav bar. Was there any change when you used the new image?

Comment: Sorry Nick, it was 64 height (128px), check this out, http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/